# Bearer token expires after 3599, refresh data steps

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

The bearer token expires after 3599. I still need to refresh it and keep using it. How is that possible? I am looking for a simple code example to do that. I am using Python

```
 # Create an MSAL instance providing the client_id, authority and client_credential parameters
  client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

  # First, try to lookup an access token in cache
  token_result = client.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

  # If the token is available in cache, save it to a variable
  if token_result:
    access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
    print('Access token was loaded from cache')

  # If the token is not available in cache, acquire a new one from Azure AD and save it to a variable
  if not token_result:
    token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
    print('New access token was acquired from Azure AD')
```

Answer (score 1):

By checking if token has expired and then refreshing it?

The function acquire_new_token to request a new token using client credentials, and a function is_token_expired to check if the token is expired. Script checks if the token is in the cache and if it's expired, then it acquires a new one.

```
import msal
import time

# Replace these values with your actual values
client_id = "your_client_id"
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id"
client_secret = "your_client_secret"
scope = ["your_scope"]

# Create an MSAL instance providing the client_id, authority, and client_credential parameters
client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

# Function to acquire a new token using client credentials
def acquire_new_token():
    token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    return token_result['access_token']

# Function to check if the token is expired
def is_token_expired(token_result):
    expiration_time = token_result['expires_in'] + token_result['expires_on']
    current_time = int(time.time())
    return current_time > expiration_time

# First, try to lookup an access token in the cache
token_result = client.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

# If the token is available in cache and not expired, save it to a variable
if token_result and not is_token_expired(token_result):
    access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
    print('Access token was loaded from cache')

# If the token is not available in cache or expired, acquire a new one from Azure AD
if not token_result or is_token_expired(token_result):
    access_token = acquire_new_token()
    print('New access token was acquired from Azure AD')

# Now, you can use the 'access_token' variable for your API requests
print(access_token)
```

Comment: Trying this out. Will it result in duplication of files that were read by the first token and the renewed token?

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code is/might be doing with files etc. So can't comment on that but the behaviour of the rest of the code should essentially remain the same.

Comment: @WhoamI is the answer acceptable? or did you run into issues?